# What did the Early Church Fathers think about pets (animals) going to Heaven upon death?

Tags: heaven, church-fathers

Many people believe that a pet goes to Heaven upon its death. I was curious, what did the Early Church Fathers (e.g., Augustine, John of Damascus, Tertullian, etc.) say about this?

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [According to the Bible, do animals have souls?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/185)

Comment: "Outside are the dogs" (Revelation 22:15).  So... as much as it pains me, all dogs do not go to heaven... maybe cats do, though.

Comment: Did the Early Church Fathers have pets, or just working animals?

Comment: Please note this question is **about the church fathers**. Answers not addressing the fathers and building only on Scripture, opinion or other sources are not valid and will be removed.

Comment: I thought keeping pets was a relatively modern idea. I think until recently, animals were viewed as useful or not, and of the many uses assigned to animals, companionship was rare.

Comment: First, why do we worry about pets? Many *people* will die today without knowing Christ, shouldn't that be our focus? Secondly, why care about where the Church Fathers stand on any issue at all? They are people just like us, learning from their wisdom is *not* the same as basing our beliefs on theirs.

Comment: As I interpret 'early church fathers', as the people that wrote the bible. Then we must look at what was written. There is writings on there being animals in heaven. But some say Jesus only came to save humans. This is true, Jesus said I came to save the lost, a well person does not need a doctor etc. He eat with a tax collector, because he needed and wanted Jesus's help.

Comment: @richard: No, the phrase doesn't refer to the people who wrote the Bible. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Fathers

Comment: @Will: It doesn't matter what you think of them. The question is what it is, and that's not up for debate.

Comment: @H3br3wHamm3r81, The "church fathers" are long dead and gone, how exactly are you going to get any answers other than what people today think of them?

Comment: @Will: By what they wrote, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read a lot of the early Church Fathers and don't recall them addressing this issue.  A good site for reading their writings (for free) is at:  http://www.ccel.org/fathers.html

Generally, the early Fathers are focused more on answering pagan criticisms of the Christian faith, arguing against heretical ideas, and generally building up the faith of believers.  Ignatius, for instance, wrote letters of exhortation to the congregations he was passing by while on his way to Rome for execution.  Clement of Rome wrote to the church in Corinth, calling them to remember the words of Paul which he had written to them.  Justin Martyr wrote two Apologies to the Roman emperors, defending the Christian faith.  Irenaeus wrote "Against the Heresies" to counter heretical beliefs and to defend the "rule of faith" (i.e. the creedal belief taught by the Apostles as they founded congregations).

My sense, then, in reading the Fathers is that the issue of pets was not something they were concerned about.  I'm not sure how they would have taught about this issue, either, since the Bible is largely silent on the topic.  What the Bible does depict, however, is that God is concerned for His whole creation, and that Jesus Christ is redeeming and restoring all of his creation.  This is seen also, for instance, in the fact that God had Noah preserve the animals on the ark.

Thus, in Revelation, after the resurrection we see the "new heavens and new earth" that has been fully restored to the perfection in which God originally created it.  Things will be perfect, but different there, and we don't quite know what it will be like, other than that it will be "very good" (cf. Isaiah 65:17, Isaiah 66:22, 1 Peter 3:13, Revelation 21:1, Matthew 22:29-32).

To the underlying question of "will we see our pets again in heaven or at the resurrection," the only answer I have is that God doesn't tell us; I suspect that's why the early Church Fathers don't seem to have addressed the question either.  However, we trust that all things will be made right by God at the resurrection and that He will complete everything according to His goodness.